# MinusValue + MinusValue returning a positive value in java long data type

Tags: java, java-8

Im having a one or many long values in a linkedList. When I tested with values -100 and 1 Im getting a wrong result for this below code.

Why -somevalue + -somevalue gives a positive value as result rather a negative value.

```
long bigpow =(long) Math.pow(Math.pow(10000,10000), 10000);
bigpow *= -1;
while(itr1.hasNext()){  
          long temp = itr1.next();
           recount1 = (recount1)+ ( temp * (long) Math.pow(bigpow,xpow));

      }
```

My recount1 value is positive but It should be negative. Im not sure where I go wrong trying to solve this issue for past 2days.

Comment: Overflow. `long` is only 64-bits.

Comment: Consider using the [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class instead of long.

Comment: @Bernat there is not enough RAM in the entire universe to hold the exact integer value of `Math.pow(Math.pow(10000,10000), 10000)` in a BigInteger

Comment: In fact consider ReallyBigInteger with 10 000 ^ 10 000 ^ 10 000.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException I didn't actually do the math, you're probably right.

Comment: ` bigpow ` is a number that is many times bigger than the number of atoms in the observable universe. You'll need to use FORTRAN on a supercomputer.

Comment: I like that `println` call. Just making and printing a string that long will probably cause your app to run out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

You are going over the maximum long value by a lot.

The maximum number for a primitive long is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

You already reached this value by doing simply this:

```
long bigpow = (long) Math.pow(10000, 5);
```

Having this number exponentially growing there is no way you can fit this anywhere.